# How to handle Thread was being aborted Exception vb.net/C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, exception, httpresponse, threadabortexception

I've seen several questions regarding this issue but I've not found an apt answer for my issue. 
Initially I was using the following code after writing json in a function

```
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = True;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Was getting `Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent` exception.

So I altered the code to

```
try {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Data);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
} catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException exc) {
    try {
        //Sends the response buffer
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        // Prevents any other content from being sent to the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
        //Directs the thread to finish, bypassing additional processing
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
              //Log Exception
    }

}
```

All these code are in function(lets say) `writeData()` and its called by a function called `CallWriteData`. Now the exception has been successfully handled in `WriteData()` function but its throwing `Thread was being aborted` exception in the parent function `CallWriteData`.

To be honest its not a major issue in my project but it would be nice if I fix this annoying issue. Also this exception in  `CallWriteData` not every-time(sometimes its successfully handled).

Comment: Well, I'm going to assume the thread being aborted is the http thread. If it has been aborted in the call to writeData(), why would you expect any later operations on the same thread to work?

If writeData() already handles the exception, why are you handling it again?

Comment: u mean why I'm handling it in `CallWriteData` ?

Comment: Yes. If you call writeData() from CallWriteData() to take care of writing data and it handles all related exceptions, why are you rethrowing the exception and handling it a second time in CallWriteData()?

Comment: Ok in my project `WriteData()` function is called from many functions,`CallWriteData()` is one of the function . In all functions I catch the exceptions and log it. Now because of this `thread abort` exception I'm getting a lot of error log. I can't remove the exceptions from the functions where WriteData() is called because I can't log other exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,this helped me to handle `Thread was being aborted` exception,

```
try
{
   //Write HTTP output
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Data);
}  
catch (Exception exc) {}
finally {
   try 
    {
      //stop processing the script and return the current result
      HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
     } 
   catch (Exception ex) {} 
   finally {
        //Sends the response buffer
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        // Prevents any other content from being sent to the browser
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
        //Directs the thread to finish, bypassing additional processing
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        //Suspends the current thread
        Thread.Sleep(1);
     }
   }
```

if you use the following the following code instead of `HttpContext.Current.Response.End()` , you will get `Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent` exception.

```
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = True;
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Another Fix which I found is `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();`

```
   try 
 {
    //Write HTTP output
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Data);
  } catch (Exception exc) {} 
  finally {
    try {
     //Notifies a host that execution is about to enter a region of code in which the effects of a thread abort or unhandled exception might jeopardize other tasks in the application domain.
     Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
         } catch (Exception ex) {} 
    finally {
    //Sends the response buffer
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    // Prevents any other content from being sent to the browser
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
    //Directs the thread to finish, bypassing additional processing
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
         }
   }
```

Now I'm a relieved man.

Answer (score -2):

This is how IIS works. It starts a new thread for the new request. The thread does it's stuff, and when it ends the thread is aborted. Normally, this happens in the .NET plumbing and it's handles there. However, it you do something like a Server.Redirect() it'll also get aborted - in your code. Similarly with completing the request yourself as you do. IIS says "It's sent the return, so kill it." That's how it works.

(The thread is probably saved for re-use by another request, but the code just finished on it is aborted.)

Comment: It is not how IIS works...Normally threads don't get aborted... (Consider adding links that prove your point of view, preferably MSDN or http://www.asp.net/ )

Comment: I used to get thread aborted exception like you said when I use `response .redirect`, but if I use `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` , it doesn't throw any exceptions. I used get emails whenever I get exceptions, so its bit annoying. so there is not other way to fix this issue or bypass it?

Comment: My own code that redirected got ThreadAbortedExceptions. I don't do much web-stuff nowadays, but it certainly used to work like that.

Comment: well if you use  these codes in redirects `Response.Redirect("example.aspx", False);Response.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` , you don't get any exceptions .